# How to get additional information associated to a python concurrent.future?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I am trying to download a bunch of files from S3 in python. To speed it up, I use

```
def sync(self):
    def wait_for_job(job):
        (src_filename, dst_filename, f) = job
        try:
            result = f.result()
            logging.info("Download ok: {}, result={}".format(dst_filename, result))
        except IOError as e:
            logging.info("Download error: {} - {}".format(dst_filename, e))
            self.projectInfo.downloaded_files[src_filename] = 0

    while self.pending_jobs:
        wait_for_job(self.pending_jobs.pop(0))


def getFiles(files_to_download):
    for src, dst in files_to_download:
        self.pending_jobs.append( (src, dst, self.executor.submit(s3_ops.copy_file, src, dst)) )
```

Now, I'd like to use `concurrent.futures.as_completed()`. As it takes a list of futures, I can't pass `self.pending_jobs` to it (it's a list of tuples).

I could make `self.pending_jobs` just a list of futures, whose function would return not only result, but also src and dst:

```
def sync(self):
    def wait_for_job(f):
        try:
            (src_filename, dst_filename, result) = f.result()
            logging.info("Download ok: {}, result={}".format(dst_filename, result))
        except IOError as e:
            ### Can't get the value of dst_filename
            logging.info("Download error: {} - {}".format(dst_filename, e))
            self.projectInfo.downloaded_files[src_filename] = 0

    for job in concurrent.futures.as_completed(self.pending_jobs):
        wait_for_job(job)


def getFiles(files_to_download):
    for src, dst in files_to_download:
        l = lambda s, d: (s, d, ops.copy_file(s, d))
        self.pending_jobs.append( self.executor.submit(l, src, dst) )
```

I would get them after calling `future.result()`, as part of the tuple it returns. But in the case of an exception, I wouldn't be able to get anything.

Is there any way to accomplish this? I would expect `as_completed` including some parameter in the line of `key` in `sorted` (i.e., to let it know how to extract the future from an item in the list), but it doesn't seem to be there.